# How do I fix my XSLT to correctly translate XML to HTML as expected?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using XSLT to translate XML to HTML.

The XML is:

```
<PARA>
    1050
    <EMPH STYLE="min_max">
        <EMPH HL="LOW">-50</EMPH>
        <EMPH HL="HIGH">+50</EMPH>
    </EMPH>
     min
    <EMPH BOLD="0" HL="HIGH" ITAL="0" SMALLCAPS="0">-1</EMPH>
</PARA>
```

How I do correctly render the output as:

`1050 -50 +50 min<sup>-1</sup>`

Currently I am getting `1050  min -50 +50 <sup>-1</sup>`

My XSLT is:

```
<xsl:template match="PARA"> 
    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="EMPH">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="EMPH"/>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="EMPH">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@BOLD=1"><b><xsl:value-of select="."/></b></xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@HL='HIGH'"><sup><xsl:value-of select="."/></sup></xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: So what are the exact rules? Why is `<EMPH HL="HIGH">+50</EMPH>` not transformed into `<sup>+50</sup>`? Also which version of XSLT, which XSLT processor do you use?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Yes, you are correct, by my assumption, if ```HL="HIGH"``` is for superscript, then ```HL="LOW"``` should be for subscript. Then the output should be something like ```1010<sub>-50</sub><sup>+50</sup>min<sup>-1</sup>```. But I am not doing that for ```STYLE="min_max"```. I am using xslt version 2.0 and Saxon 9.1.0.8J from Saxonica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to process the attributes with a recursive template and keep the mapping from attribute names to HTML elements in a map (in XSLT as supported since Saxon 9.8 you can use an XPath 3.1 map but in XSLT 2 if you need to use that rather old version of Saxon you can of course define some variable holding an XML structure mapping the names e.g. `<map><att name="BOLD">b</att></map>`):

```
  <xsl:param name="att-map" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)"
    select="map { 'BOLD' : 'b', 'HL' : 'sup', 'ITAL' : 'i' }"/>

  <xsl:template match="PARA">
      <p>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="EMPH[@STYLE = 'min_max']/EMPH">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="EMPH">
      <xsl:param name="atts" select="@*[. = ('1', 'HIGH')]"/>
      <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="head($atts)">
              <xsl:element name="{$att-map(local-name(head($atts)))}">
                  <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
                      <xsl:with-param name="atts" select="tail($atts)"/>
                  </xsl:apply-templates>
              </xsl:element>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxDjims/1

I have also used XSLT/XPath 3 functions `head` and `tail` there but you can of course use XPath 2 `subsequence` equivalents or `$atts[1]` and `$atts[position() gt 1]`.

Another option would be to write templates for the attributes you want to transform:

```
  <xsl:param name="att-map" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)"
    select="map { 'BOLD' : 'b', 'HL' : 'sup', 'ITAL' : 'i' }"/>

  <xsl:template match="PARA">
      <p>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="EMPH[@STYLE = 'min_max']/EMPH" priority="5">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@BOLD[. = 1] | @ITAL[. = 1] | @HL[. = 'HIGH']">
      <xsl:param name="atts"/>
      <xsl:element name="{$att-map(local-name())}">
          <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="$atts">
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="head($atts)">
                      <xsl:with-param name="atts" select="tail($atts)"/>
                  </xsl:apply-templates>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="../node()"/>
              </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="EMPH[@*[. = ('1', 'HIGH')]]">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="head(@*[. = ('1', 'HIGH')])">
          <xsl:with-param name="atts" select="tail(@*[. = ('1', 'HIGH')])"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="text-only-copy"/>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxDjims/2

As I guess the SMALLCAPPS can't be transformed with a simple attribute to element name map it might also help to write some more templates to allow for more flexibility, the following uses a base template for the recursive processing, it is called with `<xsl:next-match/>` by other, more specialized templates describing the transformation of attributes to elements:

```
  <xsl:param name="att-map" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)"
    select="map { 'BOLD' : 'b', 'HL' : 'sup', 'ITAL' : 'i' }"/>

  <xsl:template match="PARA">
      <p>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="EMPH[@STYLE = 'min_max']/EMPH" priority="5">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@BOLD[. = 1] | @ITAL[. = 1] | @HL[. = 'HIGH']" mode="attributes-to-elements">
      <xsl:element name="{$att-map(local-name())}">
          <xsl:next-match/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@SMALLCAPS[. = 1]" mode="attributes-to-elements">
      <span style="font-variant: small-caps">
          <xsl:next-match/>
      </span>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*" mode="attributes-to-elements">
      <xsl:param name="remaining-atts" tunnel="yes"/>
      <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$remaining-atts">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="head($remaining-atts)" mode="#current">
                  <xsl:with-param name="remaining-atts" tunnel="yes" select="tail($remaining-atts)"/>
              </xsl:apply-templates>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="../node()"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>      
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="EMPH[@*[. = ('1', 'HIGH')]]">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="head(@*[. = ('1', 'HIGH')])" mode="attributes-to-elements">
          <xsl:with-param name="remaining-atts" tunnel="yes" select="tail(@*[. = ('1', 'HIGH')])"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxDjims/3

In the end it might be simpler to do a two step transformation that first normalizes the input you have to strip any attributes not indicating some special HTML styling or wrapping and also to transform the attributes to normalized elements, then the second step can more easily use normal, elements-based `apply-templates` to simply transform the nested input to nested HTML.

Comment: Thanks for a good-looking answer! I am trying to downgrade it for my version of Saxon 9.1. I have defined the map, but now I need to figure out how to iterate over each found attribute, to apply the mapping. I don't have the ```head()``` and ```tail()``` functions.

Comment: @KevinM, as I said, `head($seq)` is `$seq[1]` or `subsequence($seq, 1, 1)` and `tail($seq)` is `$seq[position() gt 1]` or `subsequence($seq, 2)`.

Comment: As for the mapping, assuming you have e.g. `<xsl:variable name="map"><map><att name="BOLD">b</att>...</map></xsl:variable>`, declare a key `<xsl:key name="map" match="map/att" use="@name"/>` and instead of e.g. `$att-map(local-name())` use e.g. `key('map', local-name(), $map)`: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxDjims/4

Comment: At http://xsltransform.net/gVK9HpL I have spelled out the "downgrade" for XSLT 2.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this works:

```
<xsl:template match="PARA">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="EMPH">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@BOLD=1"><b><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></b></xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@HL='HIGH'"><sup><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></sup></xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

I would like to know if there is a better way to handle the multiple attributes of the `EMPH` element than `<xsl:choose>`, because this way I have to handle all combinations as unique `<xsl:when>` checks.

For example, I have to check for "bold", "superscript" and "bold and superscript" as three different clauses.